# NSDate compare result is not NSOrderedSame after conversion with NSDateComponents

Tags: ios, objective-c

In order to pass the date values to a C++ library, I need to extract the year, month, day and etc out from the `NSDate`. And I use `NSDateComponents`, and will reconstruct the `NSDate` with `NSDateComponents` again from the C++ library. But I notice that, the round trip comparison always failed even though the `NSDate` I log looks exactly the same. Here is a simple unit test:

```
- (void) testCalender {
    NSDate *timestamp = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear |NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:timestamp];
    NSLog(@"%@", components);
    //Calendar Year: 2016
    //Month: 2
    //Leap month: no
    //Day: 26
    //Hour: 10
    //Minute: 48
    //Second: 36
    NSDate *result = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];

    NSLog(@"%@", timestamp); // 2016-02-26 15:48:36 +0000
    NSLog(@"%@", result);    // 2016-02-26 15:48:36 +0000

    XCTAssertEqual([timestamp compare:result], NSOrderedSame); // Failed
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `NSDate` is using sub-second precision internally. When you query `[NSDate date]` you get a date that likely has a non-zero nanosecond part. But when you're recreating it, you miss that part and they differ very slightly. So you also need to handle `NSCalendarUnitNanosecond`.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` is nanosecond-precise. As soon as you reassemble those `NSDateComponents`, the not-set ones will be `0`, yielding slightly different dates.